# draw a line using a latitude longitude in GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools

I want to draw a line from the values in my array's. I have 2 arrays namely `latitude` and `longitude`, which contains the values. I want to draw a line with those values on my shape file. (".SHP") using geotools.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to create a `POINT`, then create a `FeatureCollection` and then a shapefile :

```
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = FeatureCollections.newCollection();
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
featureBuilder.add(point);
SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
collection.add(feature);
```

read [geoTools feature tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html) for more information.